# How to solve the error installing the python packages in virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip

I am installing some packages in my virtual environment by using pip, but it is showing me following error:

`pip install Flask-Ask==0.9.8`

and output is:

`Collecting Flask-Ask==0.9.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/f5/d4709ae94584a0b1541e9b52b2d25a8a1bdb6e2da9d6870f23fdd0523a30/Flask-Ask-0.9.8.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/nisha/v2env/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wf2c65i_/Flask-Ask/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wf2c65i_/Flask-Ask/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-wf2c65i_/Flask-Ask/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wf2c65i_/Flask-Ask/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wf2c65i_/Flask-Ask/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: Are you using pip version 10?

Comment: @Snuffles my pip version is: `pip3 -V`
`pip 19.3 from /home/nisha/v2env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

Comment: I think this is quite outdated, try rolling back to pip version 9. I'll show you instructions when I get to my pc

Comment: @Snuffles, I downgrade my pip to version 9 and it worked..!!! Thank You.

Comment: @Snuffles, Hey but now when I use pip to install another packages it is showing me    `You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`    Is it okay to keep version 9?? or should I upgrade it again??

Comment: Oh I see, it's just telling you there is a more up to date version of pip. You can update it after your done with the flask-ask module.

Comment: If I helped you out, consider accepting my answer to render this matter closed. Unless there is more I'm not aware of =)

Comment: okay thank you so much :) @Snuffles

Comment: Your welcome, enjoy your day =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an outdated module. Thus pip must use a earlier version. So from what I have gathered, anything past version 10 pip is not able to find flask- ask (the req.txt file I think)

Try:

```
python -m pip install pip==9.0.1
```

Note:
You will have to update pip again after you are done with this module.

When finished with the module:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```